# Can I use a static accessor as my DI approach?

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

This question is more philosophical.

I'm using DI and there are [three](https://devopedia.org/dependency-injection) ways to do it:

1. Constructor injection
2. Method injection
3. Property injection

Yet all of them incur a huge amount of boilerplate code. For each service/business class and each controller you literally need to write at least a couple of line of codes to make it work.

In a real world application with thousands of files, this means at least some ten thousands of lines of boilerplate code.

Is is possible to not use any of these methods? And use a static accessor?

Instead of:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private SomeService _someService;
    private SomeService _otherService;


    public SomeClass (ISomeService someService, IOtherService otherService)
    {
        _someService = someService;
        _otherService = otherService;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
        _someService.DoFirst();
        _otherService.DoSecond();
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write this code?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Accessor.SomeService.DoFirst();
        Accessor.SecondService.DoSecond();
    }
}
```

And make the `Accessor` a public static class, and make one property for each service?

If that's a legit way for DI and IoC, then we can literally strip away tens of thousands of boilerplate code and fasten our development speed to a noticeable amount.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is: no, this is not possible — or at least, not within the context of Dependency Injection.

What you are describing is *not* Dependency Injection any longer, and doesn't provide the same benefits that Dependency Injection provides. The pattern you are describing comes close to a mix between the Service Locator and Ambient Context patterns, and I would even argue that anything else you try to come up with that deviates from the use of constructor, property, or method injection will result in in similar downsides as Service Locator and Ambient Context cause.

Service Locator captures some of the same benefits that Dependency Injection has—mainly loose coupling—but fails on many other aspects. There are many resources that describe why Service Locator is a bad idea, such as answers here on Stack Overflow, and I provided my own explanation [here](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/) (that article is an excerpt from [my book](https://mng.bz/BYNl) where [Mark Seemann](https://blog.ploeh.dk/) and I spend a whole section on the downsides of Service Locator).

[Ambient Context](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-ambient-context-anti-pattern/) focuses on exposing a single dependency through a static field. Each property in your static `Accessor` class can, therefore, be viewed as an individual Ambient Context. Ambient Context comes with its own set of downsides.

Now about the complaint of boilerplate; please note that boilerplate in itself is not a problem. The end goal in software development is providing value to the business and we want to do this in the most cost efficient way possible. And one of the most important abilities of software to keep the [total cost of ownership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_cost_of_ownership) as low as possible is by making software maintainable.

Boilerplate code *can* have a big negative impact on maintainability, but I would argue that the boilerplate that DI brings in earlier versions of, for instance, C# has little to no negative impact on maintainability. Yes, I find it annoying that I have to define a private field, a constructor argument, and assign one to the other, which takes three lines per dependency. I find it annoying and it produces some noise on the top of the class, while I rather have a simple 'definition' of what dependencies a class requires.

But that said, from a maintainability perspective, those three lines per dependency hardly have a negative impact. For instance, they will not cause [Shotgun Surgery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shotgun_surgery) and changes arise. The code and change is limited to one dependency in one single class. I also find the argument that stripping these lines of code will "fasten our development speed to a noticeable amount" untrue. Or at least, I've been practicing DI for over one and a half decade and I personally never experienced that this boilerplate slows down development, especially to a "noticeable amount."

That said, newer versions of *do* C# provide features that limit the amount of boilerplate / noise that the use of Dependency Injection brings with older versions of the language. C# 9, for instance, introduced the [record type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record) syntax, which allows you to reduce the code to a clear and concise definition of the class with its dependencies. This is what your `SomeClass` will look like when applying C# 9 record type syntax:

```cs
public record SomeClass(SomeService SomeService, SomeService OtherService)
{
    public void Do()
    {
        SomeService.DoFirst();
        OtherService.DoSecond();
    }
}
```

In this case, the C# compiler generates the constructor and storage (properties in this case rather than fields) for the dependencies under the coders. This can be seen when viewing the actual generated IL code. This is still 100% Dependency Injection without resorting to any anti-pattern, such as Service Locator.

The only downside of records in C# is that they behave like value types, meaning that C# will also generate `ToString()`, `GetHashCode()`, Equals()`, and other methods on the type. Those methods will typically not be useful, but on the other hand, also not causing any trouble is my experience.

With C# 12, Microsoft will probably introduce primary constructors in classes which means you can write the following code:

```cs
// C# 12 proposal
public class SomeClass(SomeService someService, SomeService otherService)
{
    public void Do()
    {
        someService.DoFirst();
        otherService.DoSecond();
    }
}
```

In this case, the C# compiler will turn the dependencies in the "primary constructor" into private fields and the only thing that is generated on your behalf is the constructor and the assignment. Methods like `ToString(),` GetHashCode()`, and` Equals()` will not be overridden, which means the code above is on an IL level identical to the first code snippet in your question.

I've written this answer in the context of C#, and I have no idea how other languages are dealing with this. They might all be doing this in their own way and improving the language at their own pace. Your mileage might vary, but remember that the boilerplate will unlikely cause maintainability issues, while Dependency Injection can improve the maintainability of your application.

Comment: Thank you so much for this in-depth analysis. Now that you introduced me to the Service Locator and Ambient Context patterns, may I ask if they are better than direct dependencies or not? I mean, can they be regarded as good middle solutions to migrate to, as a path to DI?

Comment: If you read [this](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-service-locator-anti-pattern/) and [this](https://freecontent.manning.com/the-ambient-context-anti-pattern/), which are excerpts from my book, you'll see that Mark Seemann and I call these two patterns "anti-patterns." Since we label them as anti-patterns you can safely assume that we find them much worse compared to using Dependency Injection.

Comment: However, when it comes to refactoring legacy code, I would say that *everything* is allowed as an intermediary step, even the use of anti-patterns, to improve a code base, as long as you and the rest of the team are very clear on the fact that 1. you are using anti-patterns, 2. why they are anti-patterns, 3. that they are intermediary, and 4. you have a clear plan on getting rid of them in the near future.